# How can I configure Mac OS X's Outlook

Tags: macos, email, exchange, office-for-mac, microsoft-outlook-2011

I have Mac OS X 10.6 and Microsoft Outlook 2011 for Mac. I wish to configure Outlook to use Exchange. I have tried fondling with the settings but to no avail. The setting I use for Outlook 2010 for Windows as as follows:

1. Exchange Server: foo.bar, Use Cached Exchange Mode.
2. Connection Tab -> connect to my exchange mailbox using HTTP.
3. Exchange proxy settings -> Proxy Server: owa.foo.bar, check box "on fast networks...", check box "on slow networks..."
4. Proxy Authentication: basic.

How can I configure this settings on the Mac? Thanks,

Comment: When I created my account, I didn't have any problems. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Your Exchange administrator will have to provide you with the settings required.

I'm afraid you can't work them out from the settings you have in Outlook 2010, since the two programs use entirely different connection methods. You could maybe make some guesses but that is all they would be. Easier to talk to the Exchange admin. We don't often bite.

You will need:
The Exchange Web Services URL, and maybe a port number.
Your Domain name, domain username, domain password.
An LDAP server's address for directory lookups, and maybe a search base.

Comment: You don't *often* bite? ;-)

Comment: Well, we might do if people start trying to guess out EWS urls!